# LinQ to Entities: Doing the opposite query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I wrote this:

```
var destinations = db.DestinationDetails.
    Where(dd => dd.Language.Lang == "en-US" &&
        dd.Destination.Client.Any(c => c.Email == "abc@yahoo.com"));
```

How can I retrieve destinationDetails that client with email abc@yahoo.com doesn't have?

This doesn't work:

```
var destinations = db.DestinationDetails.
    Where(dd => dd.Language.Lang == "en-US" &&
        dd.Destination.Client.Any(c => c.Email != "abc@yahoo.com"));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use All instead of Any:

```
dd.Destination.Client.All(c => c.Email != "abc@yahoo.com")
```

Comment: @Vans y, its negating the expression :P - mine reads: all clients doesn't have this email, crhis's reads: there isn't any client that has this email - you can see why they are equivalent :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var destinations = db.DestinationDetails.
    Where(dd => dd.Language.Lang == "en-US" &&
        !dd.Destination.Client.Any(c => c.Email == "abc@yahoo.com"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var destinations =(db.DestinationDetails.
    Where(dd => dd.Language.Lang == "en-US" &&
    dd.Destination.Client.Any(c => c.Email != "abc@yahoo.com")).Select c).ToList();
```

Try this, you may get result...